# System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno

Tags: c#, azure

When I deploy my changes to azure web app I am getting below exception :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXjlk.png)

But no local it's working fine.
I have check my file IsReadOnly=false or not.

Using a below code to achieve

```html
 var fileName = "myfilename.json";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), fileName);
            var configJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(integrationsConfiguration);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(configJSON);
            }
            return true;
```

Comment: You may want to write a file, but if the file system is readonly, you wont be able. Think about a DVD/Bluray, if the media is read only you cant write in it.